# Product of inner products is trace of outer products

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Let's fix vectors $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2' \in \mathbb{R}^p$. One step in a computation in my lecture notes asserts that:

$$x_1^Tx_2\cdot y_1^Ty_2 = \operatorname{Tr}(x_2y_1^T\cdot y_1x_1^T).$$

It is not clear to me why this is the case. Could someone kindly provide clarification?

Comment: are the indices correct? what is difference between $y_2'$ and $y_2$?

Comment: hint for the correct statement: you can shift the factors in a trace in circle, assuming dimension compatibility: $tr(ABC) = tr(CAB) = tr(BCA)$.